# How to replace one word whose last character is special character by regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Here is my code

```
String textContent = "L.A. is best place";
String reg = "L.A.";
reg = reg.replaceAll("\\.","\\\\.");

String regex ="\\s*\\b" + reg + "\\b\\s*";

pat = Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
mat = pat.matcher(textContent);
textContent = mat.replaceAll(" (Name) ");
```

I hope the final textContent is (Name) is best place. But it is not.
But if String reg = "L.A". The final textContent is (Name) . is best place.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you want `reg = Pattern.quote(reg)`

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this regex,

```
String s = "L.A. is best place";
String replaced = s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b[a-z.]+[*+.$()\\[\\]]", "(Name)");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

OUTPUT:

```
(Name) is best place
```